# Adding external scripts to angular 2

Tags: angular

So for example if you wanted to include a payment system such as stripe into your angular application. however, the only way is to access the script like this.

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
```

I know that its not a great thing to just throw that into the index.html file. I also saw people mention [articles](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/07/05/using-stripe-payment-with-angular-2/) accessing the window like this

```
(<any>window)
```

in there angular application. I don't think it's a good idea to reference the global window object.

So whats the best or close to best alternative that would allow someone to use external scripts in their angular 2 modules.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using typed version of the library from here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/stripe

If you encounter a library that is not present in [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) you can always create a type definition of that lib and push to DefinitelyTyped's repo.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is to use a package manager like `npm` or `bower`. Then you can include the files in the angular-config files. Some packages then provide their TypeScript typings, so you easily can import them in your TypeScript modules.

If there is no package-manager package for your needed library, I would maybe copy the script into my own js-directory. So I can maintain the versions for the script better, than just use a CDN.

And my preferred way to handle libraries, which don't provide typings for TypeScript. I create my own typings/interfaces and cast the needed object. Example:

```
interface Greeter
{
    sayHello(name: string): string;
    sayGoodbye(name: string): string;
}

(<Greeter>window.greeter).sayHello('Peter');
```

Then I have the auto-completion and correct types.

I'm not sure if this is the best advice/alternative, but it's my way how to do it. But I'm interested in the advices of others!